# Where is __new__ defined in python3?

Tags: python

In Python 2:

```
>>> class A:
...  pass
... 
>>> A.__new__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: class A has no attribute '__new__'
>>> class A(object):
...  pass
... 
>>> A.__new__
<built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x1062fe2a0>
```

Conclusion: `object` contains `__new__` and subclasses inherit the method.

in Python 3:

```
>>> class A:
...  pass
... 
>>> A.__new__
<built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x100229940>
```

`__new__` is a defined method in our class, without any inheritance. How does this work? Where does `__new__` "come from"?

Comment: Check out `A.__mro__`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 3, if you create a class without adding a parent class it automatically inherits from object. You can't create old style classes anymore like Python 2.

Example:

```
class A: # gets defaulted to class A(object):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

All classes in Python3  are subclasses of `object` as you can see from the mro:

```
>>> class A: pass
... 
>>> A.__mro__
(<class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
```

`class A(object)` is still done in some Python 3 code to maintain backward compatibility with Python 2.